# Select helper tag not showing items from binding

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to show a drop down list of options to filter with, but the select helper tag is not showing the bounded list.

This is the **Home Controller**:

```
public IActionResult Index(string SelectedClinic)
    {
        GetReservationsAsync();

        HomeIndexvmIns.Clinics = new SelectList(_clinicsLookup, "Id", "ClinicName");

        return View(HomeIndexvmIns);
    }
```

This is the **HomeIndexViewModel**:

```
public HomeIndexViewModel()
    {
        Reservations = new List<ReservationViewModel>();
    }

    public List<ReservationViewModel> Reservations { get; set; }
    public SelectList Clinics { get; set; }
    public string SelectedClinic { get; set; }
```

And this is the **Index View**:

```
@model schedule.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel


<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
<p>
    <select asp-for="SelectedClinic" asp-items="Model.Clinics"></select>
</p>
</form>


<table class="table">
<tbody>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        Reservation Id
    </th>
    <th>
        Start Date/Time
    </th>
    <th>
        End Date/Time
    </th>
    <th>
        Status
    </th>
    <th>
        Clinic
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
@foreach (var item in Model.Reservations)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clinic)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried changing the SelectList to an IEnumerable of Clinics or a List of SelectListItems but still no options showed up on the drop down.

**EDIT**

I just changed the Select Tag with

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedClinic, Model.Clinics)
```

And it rendered correctly, i still wanna know why the Select Tag didn't work.

Comment: is it rendering anything for the select?  Is _clinicsLookup empty by chance?

Comment: @Mike_G No, it's just an empty dropdown, and the _cliniclookup is not empty and no object is null. I just changed the select tag with @Html.Dropdownlist() and it worked correctly. I still wanna know why the select tag not working.